# How do I cache values in .NET 4 so that they are available across multiple applications?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have created a website in Visual Studio 2010 (File -> New Web Site), and to the resulting solution file I have added two more web sites.  I know that for any one of the web sites I can use context.Application to share values among multiple users.  But is there a way to share values among users of the different web sites?

In other words, is there a "solution level" cache object of some kind in .NET?  I have not managed to find any answer through search engines.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Something like [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to share data between Webware, I prefer to develop a WCF service and provide those data via a Singleton service.

Then, each client can get same data from the Singleton service.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not have a database available on the backend?  If you do, save/read your data to the DB.  I don't know if you have any race conditions or not but this would be your main approach.

If you don't have a DB, your next choice may be reading/writing to disk.  This presumes the apps are all hosted on the same server and have read/write access to a particular directory.

My last choice would be look for some other intra-application (but same IIS) approach, though it sounds like this is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding.  Yes, I have a database.  But my application is indeed very performance-critical, which is why I need to cache values as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's not such option. The best available option would be a permanent data store (XML, database...).

Although ASP.NET support such a thing for sessions (Session state server) it doesn't support if for `IPC` of `w3wp`s.

Of course you can write your own service (you should handle concurrency issues) but it's a lot of work and error prone. Use persistent data store unless you have high rate read/writes which brings a database to it's knees (rare applications are so performance critical).

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming what I had suspected all along.  It's too bad though (but I do understand the technical issues involved).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx) - it's a distributed cache for multiple applications on multiple servers, but would run happily on a single server.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This definitely seems helpful.  I will read it now.